# Does approve take time to be confirmed, and how to deal with this in BSC?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, erc20

Hi I am doing BSC DApp using web3 with react. I am very new to this field.

I found after call `approve`, the `transfer`(or zapInToken in my case) will not be successful with complaining not enough allowance. So I added `wait allowance` to be present for 10s, but it seems in many times(50% chance) after 10s the allowance still not present. Please check the below code for more information.

Theoretically, `approve` will generate a transaction and the time to be present depends. If it is the case, Is it a standard pattern to `approve`, `wait for allowance` and `transfer`?

Thank you!

```js
const bepContract = getContract(getAddress(from), erc20ABI, library, account)
const tx = await bepContract.approve(getAddress(contracts.zap), weiAmount)
if (!tx) {
    throw new Error('Failed to approve transaction')
}
await waitAllowance(bepContract, account, getAddress(contracts.zap), weiAmount, 10) // <-- and it will stuck here in most time, the code waits for the allowance is present
await getZapContract().zapInToken(getAddress(from), weiAmount, getAddress(to)).then(logInfo).catch(logError)
```

And the waitAllowance is like below

```js
const waitAllowance = async (
  contract: Contract,
  account: string,
  to: string,
  allowanceNeeded: string,
  timesLeft: number
): Promise<void> => {
  if (timesLeft > 1) {
    const currentAllowance = await contract.allowance(account, to)
    // console.log(`I want ${allowanceNeeded}, and current is ${currentAllowance} `)
    const needed = new BigNumber(allowanceNeeded)
    const current = new BigNumber(currentAllowance.toString())
    if (current.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(needed)) {
      return
    }
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000))
    await waitAllowance(contract, account, to, allowanceNeeded, timesLeft - 1)
  }
  throw new Error('wait allowance failed for many times.')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, I need to `tx.wait`, so the working code like below:

```
const bepContract = getContract(getAddress(from), erc20ABI, library, account)
const tx = await bepContract.approve(getAddress(contracts.zap), weiAmount)
if (!tx) {
    throw new Error('Failed to approve transaction')
}
const tx = await waitAllowance(bepContract, account, getAddress(contracts.zap), weiAmount, 10)
const txResult = await tx.wait()
if (txResult.status !== 1) {
    throw new Error('Failed approve')
}
const txZap = await getZapContract().zapInToken(getAddress(from), weiAmount, getAddress(to))
const txZapResult = await txZap.wait()
if (txZapResult.status !== 1) {
    throw new Error('Failed zap')
}
```

Check this [doc](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionRequest) from more details

Answer (score 0):

Hours of debugging and realised it is due to the Node I'm using. Changed from `getblock` to `Moralis` and worked